# Is there a way to write the condition for detecting if the point belongs to area in a shorter way?

Tags: c, if-statement

[image]

I have to detect if the point belongs to the area (the pic. of it is attached). 
The condition I wrote seems too long. I am pretty sure there is a way to write it in a more simple way, but I just don't know how.
The only succeeded code of all that I've tried is presented below.

```
float x, y;   int a = 2, b = 1, r = 3;
printf("x = ", x);
scanf ("%f", &x);
printf("y = ", y);
scanf ("%f", &y);
if ( ((pow((x-a), 2) + pow((y-b), 2) <= pow(r,2)) && ((pow((x-a), 2) + pow((y-b),2) >= 1)) && (x <= 2) && (x >= -3) && (y >= -1) && (y <= 4)) || fabs(x) <= 1 && fabs(y) <=1 || (y == x+2 && y >= -1 && x >= -3))
    {
     printf ("Belongs to the area");
    }
else
    {
     printf ("Doesn't belong to the area");
    }
```

The output is correct, so I expect it would be the same.

Comment: Instead of expensive call of `pow`, use multiplication.

Comment: I strongly suggest you break that condition out into a function (e.g. `point_in_area`) where you can split it up into multiple tests that return `true`.

Comment: I cannot see, where the triangle (-3/-1),(-1/-1),(-1/1) is covered in your test

Comment: (y == x+2 && y >= -1 && x >= -3) covers the triangle, or at least that's how it should be

Comment: @DaryaWiśniewski `(y == x+2)` only covers a single line, not an area. Perhaps you meant `y <= x+2 && y >= -1 && x >= -3 && x <= -1` (untested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this one:

[image: Areas]

1. (optional) If it's outside the white rectangle, return false.
2. If it's in the red triangle, return true.
3. If it's in the yellow circle, return false.
4. If it's in the green rectangle, return true.
5. If it's in outside the pink circle, return false.
6. If it's inside the blue rectangle, return true.
7. If it's none of the above, return false.

The first step is optional, to save a few checks. It would improve performance if a good portion of your test points are far away from your area.

Code example (untested, not really a C guy):

```
bool point_in_rectangle(double x, double y, double min_x, double max_x, double min_y, double max_y) {
    if (x < min_x) return false;
    if (x > max_x) return false;
    if (y < min_y) return false;
    if (y > max_y) return false;
    return true;
}

// "easy" means it's properly aligned and has height equal to width
bool point_in_easy_triangle(double x, double y, double min_x, double max_x, double base_y) {
    if (x < min_x) return false;
    if (x > max_x) return false;
    if (y < base_y) return false;
    if (x - min_x < y - base_y) return false;
    return true;
}

bool point_in_circle(double x, double y, double center_x, double center_y, double radius) {
    double distance_x = x - center_x;
    double distance_y = y - center_y;
    double distance_squared = distance_x * distance_x + distance_y * distance_y;
    return distance_squared < (radius * radius);
}

bool point_in_my_area(double x, double y) {
    if (!point_in_rectangle(x, y, -3, 2, -1, 4)) return false;
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Take a look. Don't assume it's 100% correct :P

Comment: Looks like my solution is of the 3rd type suggested by @Steve Summit below

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn’t worry about *length* as such and would worry about clarity and maintainability,

Towards that end I would describe the requirement as

- above the line y=-1
- left of the line x=2
- outside the circle radius 1 @ (2,1)

And **either**

- inside the larger circle
- below the diagonal line

Then express those conditions in functions (reuse the in/out of a circle test!) and write your if with those functions.

—-

More generally this kind of approach is the basis of constructive planar geometry. The search terms you’ll want are “constructive solid geometry” and “signed distance functions”.

Comment: CSG is 3D (that's the "solid" in CSG)

Comment: Yes. That why this is constructive planar geometry as I said. But searching for the planar form will be vastly less remunerative and the techniques specialize easily.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your final goal is, and how hard you want to work.

It's true that the expression you have is "too long".  I doubt you can fundamentally shorten it, but you can certainly clarify it, and at the same time perhaps simplify it.  Some suggestions, in increasing order of sophistication, generality, but also difficulty:

1. Break up that huge expression onto several lines, to make it easier for the reader to follow (or to make it possible for a reader with a narrow window to even *see*!).  Then you can put a comment next to each part of the expression to explain what it's doing.
2. Break the various parts of the expression out into completely separate functions.  That way the names you choose for the functions can simultaneously be the documentaton.
3. Make those separate functions general, so that they can work on arbitrary shapes.  (That is, instead of an `in_circle(x, y)` function, that tests whether the point `x,y` is inside the one circle you care about, write something more like `in_circle(x, y, x0, y0, r)`, that tests whether the point `x,y` is inside the circle centered at `x0,y0` with radius `r`.)
4. Implement a scheme for describing arbitrary shapes (perhaps with the details read from a data file), so that there's nothing about one particular area that's hardwired in the program.
5. Implement a totally general-purpose `in_polygon` function, that lets you describe a polygon based only on the line segments making up its circumference, not as a set of simpler, overlapping sub-polygons.  (This will obviously require using a completely different algorithm.)

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the problem into sub-tests of simpler shapes is the way to go.

Edge concerns: An "outside" test using `!inside()` is a problem when the point is on the shape's edge.

To use a sub-shape test as both an "inside" and "outside", return 1 of 3 values

```
int test_rectangle(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1, double px, double py) {
  if (x1 < x0) {
    double t = x1; x1 = x0; x0 = t;
  } 
  if (y1 < y0) {
    double t = y1; y1 = y0; y0 = t;
  } 
  if (px < x0 || px > x1 || py < y0 || py > y1) return 1; // outside
  if (px > x0 && px < x1 && py > y0 && py < y1) return -1; // inside
  return 0; // edge
}
```

A circle test is more challenging. Although the standard function `hypot()` can provide more accurate results than `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`, the subtractions and `hypot()` may inject a rounding error that questions select edge case results.

```
int test_circle(double x, double y, double radius, double px, double py) {
  double hyp = hypot(x - px, y - py);
  if (hyp > radius) return 1;  // outside
  if (hyp < radius) return -1; // inside
  return 0;  // edge
}
```